# How to view my DS-160 form after submission?

Tags: visas, us-visa

I submitted a DS-160 form on 20th August. I just wanted to confirm the travel date mentioned on the form. I am only getting the option to view/print the confirmation which doesn't include any details entered by me.

Is there any way to view the form in read only mode?

Answer (score 2):

Once submitted and the appointment is scheduled, you cannot view the submitted application. Only the confirmation page.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the [Consular Electronic Application Center](https://ceac.state.gov/genniv/), enter the country in which you applied in, the code below and click *Retrieve An Application*.

Once you enter your ID and complete the security questions you can view your application including your answers.

Comment: This Answer is incorrect. See the later (and correct) Answer offered by Justin Thomas: the content of already-submitted DS-160 forms cannot be viewed online.